# appery.io fixing component in modal ionic 1

Tags: modal-dialog, fixed, appery.io

Im using ui builder of appery.io to creat this button/bar. Basiclly, I want to creat a option bar, in this case, verticaly. But, of course, a fixed bar.
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP1to.png)
I test several option in css and nothing work.

I think the problem is not of CSS, but the modal, because this code (position: fixed) work in normal page.

As you see, in normal page work:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g749h9rfzbzbly0/2021-10-22%2014.07.01.mp4?dl=0

Why dont work the same code in modal? because modal work out of scope?
I see several post about the ionic modal and I cannot find the solution.

Anyone can you help me, please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: CSS:
.btn_option{
position: fixed;
right: 10px;
bottom: 20px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
z-index: 120;
}

Answer (score 1):

1. Please move these buttons one-by-one to the header of your modal [see the example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4BgU.png)
2. Add the class "myheader" to your header component
3. And the custom CSS code:

```
.bar.myheader .buttons{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top: 50vh;
    display: block;
}
```

4. Run the Test. Now you see your toolbar in your modal [see the example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfBOl.png)